# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined - and i know there is 'fullname' input

Tags: node.js, typescript

My code:

```
interface ICheckoutWithNewPaymentRequest extends IAuthenticatedRequest {
    readonly body: Readonly<{
        products: ReadonlyArray<{
            id: string;
            size: PaymentSize;
        }>;
        save: boolean;
        payment: Readonly<{
            fullname: string;
            address: string;
            country: string;
            city: string;
            cardNumber: string;
            expiryDateMonth: PaymentMonth;
            expiryDateYear: PaymentYear;
            nameOnCard: string;
            cvv: string;
        }>;
    }>;
}


const checkoutWithNewPayment = async (
    req: ICheckoutWithNewPaymentRequest,
    res: ICheckoutWithNewPaymentResponse
) => {
    ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
        `<checkout/new>: Start processing request with user id: ${req.userId!}`
    );

    try {
        // Validate client provided details
        if (
            req.body.payment.fullname.length < 3 ||
            req.body.payment.fullname.length > 26 ||
            req.body.payment.cardNumber.length < 13 ||
            req.body.payment.cardNumber.length > 19 ||
            req.body.payment.nameOnCard.length > 26 ||
            req.body.payment.cvv.length !== 3
        ) {
            ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.error(
                `<checkout/new>: Failed because provided payment details are invalid \
with user id ${req.userId!}`
            );

            res.status(400).send({
                success: false,
                message: "Please provide valid details",
            });
            return;
        }

        let savedPayment = false;

        if (req.body.save) {
            savedPayment = true;

            // Create new payment document to store
            const newPayment = new PaymentDB({
                owner: req.userId!,
                fullname: req.body.payment.fullname,
                address: req.body.payment.address,
                country: req.body.payment.country,
                city: req.body.payment.city,
                cardNumber: req.body.payment.cardNumber,
                expiryDateMonth: req.body.payment.expiryDateMonth,
                expiryDateYear: req.body.payment.expiryDateYear,
                nameOnCard: req.body.payment.nameOnCard,
                cvv: req.body.payment.cvv,
            });

            // Storing the user document in DB
            await newPayment.save();

            ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
                `<checkout/new>: Successfully saved payment with ID: ${newPayment.id} \
for user id: ${req.userId!}`
            );
        }

        console.log(1212);
        // Processing payment
        ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
            `<checkout/new>: Successfully checked out with id: ${req.userId!}. \
Client chose${savedPayment ? "" : " not"} to save the payment.`
        );

        res.status(201).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Successfully checked out",
        });
        return;
    } catch (e) {
        ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.error(
            `<checkout/new>: Failed to checkout with user id ${req.userId!} because of server error: ${e}`
        );

        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Server error",
        });
        return;
    }
};
```

The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined
```

I don't know why `.fullname` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with (I assume) user input, since you seem to be handling data on a web server. You seem to be partially validating your data, i.e. whether it's within bounds, but you're not checking if the data structure is actually valid.

Based on your error, `.payment` has to be `undefined` _(unless that isn't (all) the code producing the error), so I assume you indeed got invalid body. Replace this part:

```
if (
    req.body.payment.fullname.length < 3 ||
    req.body.payment.fullname.length > 26 ||
    req.body.payment.cardNumber.length < 13 ||
    req.body.payment.cardNumber.length > 19 ||
    req.body.payment.nameOnCard.length > 26 ||
    req.body.payment.cvv.length !== 3
)
```

With something more thorough, like this:

```
if (
    !req.body.payment ||
    !req.body.payment.fullname ||
    req.body.payment.fullname.length < 3 ||
    req.body.payment.fullname.length > 26 ||
    !req.body.payment.cardNumber||
    req.body.payment.cardNumber.length < 13 ||
    req.body.payment.cardNumber.length > 19 ||
    !req.body.payment.nameOnCard||
    req.body.payment.nameOnCard.length > 26 ||
    !req.body.payment.cvv ||
    req.body.payment.cvv.length !== 3
)
```

And instead of a single big if-statement, you could split it up in smaller if-statements (and bundle them together in a validator function) so there's narrower error reporting to the user, e.g. "Your payment data is missing" or "Invalid full name" etc.

Comment: ok, thanks!
added that to my code.
i got another quetstion - what is the write input in postman for that interface? (the interface is in the question) i tried alot and i keep getting errors.

Comment: I haven't used Postman (and I don't know what framework you're using) but I'd assume `{ products: [...], save: ..., payment: { ... } }`, e.g. the `body` part.